# preventDefault is not working for me

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I get confused by preventDefault().

I got the following working as my test

```
$('.next').click(function(e){
        if(e.preventDefault){
            console.log("asdfnext");
            e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            console.log("next");
            return false;   
        }       
    });
```

and this is part of the working file.

```
<a class='next' href='http://www.bbc.co.uk'>Next</a>
<a class='previous' href='http://www.facebook.com'>previous</a>
```

according to the above i can stop my link going to either bbc or facebook.
and you can check it on here http://jsfiddle.net/puQ7H/

but when I try to implement this on as follow I get fail and I really like to know why

```
$('#step0Next').click(function(e){
            if($(this).is('.disabled')){
                console.log("disabled");                    
                    if(e.preventDefault){
                        console.log("asdfnext");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;   
                    }else{
                        console.log("next");
                        return false;   
                    }   

            }else{
                console.log("not disabled");    
            }

        });
```

basically ==> step0Next is my link id

and my css is as follow:

```
a.disabled { opacity:0.2; cursor: default; }
```

my idea is if the link is in ('.disable') state,
stop going to next step.

Actually link go to next step and I am being stop here. :P

Comment: for IE I am doing this. am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should work. Make sure you run the code when the document is ready.

Comment: in your fiddle you included mootools, not jQuery

Comment: this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/puQ7H/1/

Comment: @Ruben sorry for that very first time using it but i am sure i choose jquery 1.8.2

Comment: @yas no problem, you have to choose jQuery, update and set as base, then share the link, that should work

Comment: @musefan is it because of the jquery library that I am using or i see nothing much change and can you please let me know why as I am a 7 weeks old developer

Comment: Since jQuery standardizes the `event` object the `preventDefault` method should always work, which means you don't really need the `if...else` statement.

Comment: @yas, I don't know why yours isn't working. All I know is that your code worked for me fine. Do you get any javascript console errors?

Comment: @musefan no error, but got that working on jsfiddle now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if `.preventDefault` exists with your if-block, why? Try this:

```
$('#step0Next').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
        console.log("disabled");                    
        e.preventDefault();   
    } else {
        console.log("not disabled");    
    }
});
```

And actually `.hasClass()` is a little faster since it's not run through the selector engine.

Answer (score 1):

try using [event.isDefaultPrevented()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/)

```
if(e.isDefaultPrevented()){

}
```

> Description: Returns whether event.preventDefault() was ever called on this event object.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `return false;` and i don't really think that the check is relevant. Try using this instead:

```
$('#step0Next').click(function(e){
       if($(this).is('.disabled')){
            console.log("asdfnext");
            e.preventDefault();
       }else{
           console.log("not disabled");    
       }
});​
```